# My ubuntu server can ping and ssh can connect, but ssh can't do the authuncation and halt

Tags: linux, php, ssh, memcached, mongodb

I have two ubuntu server. Each running php-cgi by phpfpm, memcached, mongodb.

And these servers are not running in a high load state. After running several days. The server will halt. No service and port can be connected. Include memcached(11211), mongodb(27017). So I think its halted. But it can be ping and SSH(22) can be connected. But just connected. No authentication following as usual. And I can't in front of my server. I can control it by SSH only. But I can restart the server. After restart. everything is OK. But this circumstance will occur again and again.

I think the problem maybe cause by mongodb. Because I have other server running the same environment except mongodb. But I'm not sure.

Even if I'm sure the culprit is mongodb. I don't know how to fix it.

Anybody know how and why?

Comment: And `ssh -v ...` says...?

Comment: Did you check the log files for any of the applications? Have you set up ssh to connect without authentication? Do you have sar installed and can you look at the sar stats for the time when it stops/hangs/whatever?

Comment: ssh -v output

sshadmin@ubuntu:~$ ssh -v xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu6, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/sshadmin/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sshadmin/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sshadmin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the kernel has paniced on the server. When that happens low level networking (ie the part which happens in the kernel) often still works, so pings are replied to, TCP connections will establish etc. No user processes will run however, so the ssh daemon will never respond to anything that is sent over the connection.

Comment: yes, someone encounter the same problem of mine.
http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/8c76222c1086b40d
But no answer provided.